# Automatically Generate day according to the month

Tags: php, html

I want to automatically generate the days (numbers) according to the month.
Let's say the month is Feb., Automatically generate numbers from 1 to 28 or 29  (if it's a leap year)

I have tried the below lines of codes, and I'm not getting what I want. Anyone who can solve this?

```html
<select name="dob">
                              <option value="">---Day---</option>

                                <?php

                                  function checkMonth() {
                                      if (date('n') == 4 || date('n') == 5 || date('n') == 8 || date('n' == 11)) {
                                          echo 30;
                                      } elseif (date('n') == 2) {
                                          if (date('L') == 1) {
                                              return 29;
                                          } else {
                                              return 28;
                                          }
                                      } else {
                                          return 31;
                                      }
                                  }

                                  $k = checkMonth();

                              for ($i=1; $i<=$k; $i++) {
                                  echo "<option value=". $i ."> ". $i ."</option>";
                              }
                              ?>

                              </select>
```

Comment: You should use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

Or if its for the current month, `$count = date("t");`

Comment: @Second2None cool! I've never seen that function.

Comment: @Second2None the function is cool too, but I prefer my user-defined!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've fixed the bug

Below is the correct code

```html
<select name="dob">
                              <option value="">---Day---</option>

                                <?php

                                  function checkMonth() {
                                      if (date('n') == 4 || date('n') == 5 || date('n') == 8 || date('n' == 11)) {
                                          return 30;
                                      } elseif (date('n') == 2) {
                                          if (date('L') == 1) {
                                              return 29;
                                          } else {
                                              return 28;
                                          }
                                      } else {
                                          return 31;
                                      }
                                  }

                                  $k = checkMonth();

                              for ($i=1; $i<=$k; $i++) {
                                  echo "<option value=". $i ."> ". $i ."</option>";
                              }
                              ?>

                              </select>
```

I changed the `echo 30;` to `return 30;` and it worked... :)